# Flutter Shared Preferences cannot use async/await, so I must use a then

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

```
void _authKey() {
    Hmac hmacSha = new Hmac(sha256, utf8.encode("604ec80ffa552786f409590994dc89cfef040b72"));
    String hashValue = "";
    List<String> sortedKeys = _datas.keys.toList()..sort();
    sortedKeys.forEach((f) => hashValue += _datas[f]! + "+");
    print("waw");
    
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) => () {
      print("wow");
      String? token = prefs.getString('apitoken');

      print("the auth key is " + token.toString());

      key = hmacSha
        .convert(utf8.encode(hashValue + token.toString()))
        .toString();

    });
    
}
```

Why isn't "wow" printed ? It's never displayed in the console... But "waw" is...
So why is the `SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) => ()` neved trigged ?

Answer (score 3):

Because you are creating anonymous function

```dart
(prefs) => () {
```

What it should be

```dart
.then((prefs) {
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use SharedPrefs Class**

```
class SharedPrefs {
 static SharedPreferences _sharedPrefs;

factory SharedPrefs() => SharedPrefs._internal();

 SharedPrefs._internal();

Future<void> init() async {
_sharedPrefs ??= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 }
  String get username => _sharedPrefs.getString('apitoken') ?? "";
 set apitoken(String value) {
  _sharedPrefs.setString('apitoken', value);
   }
   }
```

**Call init function before runApp **

```
await SharedPrefs().init();
 
runApp(
MyApp(),
);

 ......
 //you can use SharedPrefs as follow
   String? token = SharedPrefs().apitoken;

  print("the auth key is " + token.toString());

    .............
```

Answer (score -1):

you can write like this too

```
final Future<SharedPreferences> sharedPreferences = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
sharedPreferences.then((value) async => {

      Future.delayed(Duration.zero,  () {

        // code more...

      })

});
```

or write like this

```
sharedPreferences.then((value) async {
    
          // code more...
    
    });
```